# Match number in square brackets and get the remaining string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like following

```
value[0]
```

1. I want to check if the string contains square brackets.
2. If yes then get the number which in the above case is `0`
3. Get the rest of the string without brackets and number which in the above case is `value`

```
var matches = this.key.match('/[([0-9]+)]/');  // 1 
if (null != matches) {
    var num = matches[1]; // 2
}
```

How can the third point be accomplished?

Comment: You need to escape the square brackets.

Comment: You clearly know that square brackets have special meaning, since you wrote `[0-9]`, which uses them specially.

Comment: That is not quite clear: 1) can there be more than one number in brackets? 2) What is the expected result then? The `'/[([0-9]+)]/'` way of defining regex is valid in PHP, not in JS, and `[` and `]` are special, hence need escaping when you need to match literal brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove wrapping quotes, and escape the brackets.

In addition, you can use another catch group to get the string. The 1st catch group should match anything that is not a bracket. Use a fallback array in case no match found, and use destructuring to get the string, and the number. If the string/number are `undefined` there's no match.

```js
var key = 'value[0]';

var [, str, number] = key.match(/([^\[]+)\[([0-9]+)\]/) || [];

console.log({ str, number });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use another capture group to get the part of the string before the square brackets.

Also, the regexp shouldn't be quoted.

```js
var key = 'value[0]'
var matches = key.match(/(\w+)\[([0-9]+)\]/);
if (null != matches) {
  var variable = matches[1];
  var num = matches[2];
}
console.log(`variable = ${variable}, index = ${num}`);
```